# react-native android studio leaves empty modules

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I uninstalled some libraries from my react-native app but weirdly they still exists in android studio. I checked package.json and they are not there anymore, also checked build.gradle and there is no any imports there either. Saw that they might exist still in .idea > modules.xml, and found that they still were  there so I removed them as well but it didn't help. I still have empty modules in Android studio like on picture. I tried to remove them from project structure with "-" but they do not appear there..., any idea how could I clean it up a bit?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like some dependencies got messed up and android studio doubled it. 
If you cannot delete them in

> project structure > modules

then try something like this:

> file > Invalid Caches/ restart

it should clean up a bit a structure.

Also pay attention that .idea might be created twice. In my case it happened that there were two directories (one in android directory, and another in app directory). Check these two places if some old modules weren't left behind, if yes then just remove them.

Comment: Oh it works! Invalid caches removed some empty modules and rest was in this second .idea which I didn't notice! Huge thanks:)